# Big Treemap with D3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to visualize a big json (~12000 lines) with a d3.js treemap as shown in [this example](http://www.billdwhite.com/wordpress/2012/12/16/d3-treemap-with-title-headers/).

Unfortunately displaying it all at once looks like is not the way to go since either it does not render at all or the lag is so high it became unusable.

Any idea on how I can render it incrementally?

Answer (score 0):

You could render using canvas instead of svg. Check out these posts:

[SVG interaction layer on top of canvas rendering example](http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/2409451)

[DOM-to-Canvas using D3](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1276463)

[OMG Particles II (Using Canvas)](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9539958)

[Post about the NYTimes's election visualization using d3.js without SVG](http://vallandingham.me/d3_without_svg.html)

Comment: On a recent voting for the next Stackoverflow moderator, several of the candidates stressed that answers that are simply links should be discouraged. I agree with them. It is not a pleasant thing to downvote someone's answer and I did not do it out of meanness or anything, but based on principle.

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes Thanks for replying. I'll keep that in mind for the future

Comment: The problem isn't with this answer, it's with the question, which is way too vague. This answer gives links because moving from DOM-based rendering to canvas (whether 2d or gl) is a big subject and requires a good deal of explanation. +1 from me!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't solved this for treemap yet, but you could use a paged implementation of [Mike Bostock's zoomable treemap](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/) to make this work.

I've done [some work on scalable d3 visualizations](http://www.billdwhite.com/wordpress/2014/05/17/d3-scalability-virtual-scrolling-for-large-visualizations/) that handle large data volumes using virtual scrolling, but for a treemap I'd suggest you follow Mike's example above.